# C. Дочерний процесс. readline

Tags: c, readline, fork

Я пишу собственную shell. Вот main:

```
void    signal_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
    {
        ft_putstr_fd("\n", 1);
        rl_on_new_line();
        rl_replace_line("", 1);
        rl_redisplay();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    (void)  argc;
    (void)  argv;
    char    *line;
    t_main  main;

    main.envp = array_2d_dup(envp);
    main.exit_status = 0;
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    while (1)
    {
        line = readline("minishell -> ");
        if (line == NULL)
            exit(0);
        if (*line == '\0')
            continue ;
        add_history(line);
        if (parser(&line, &main) != -1)
        {
            execute(&main);
            waitpid(*(main.pid), &main.exit_status, 0);
        }
        else
            exit(1);
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

Функция **парсер** разбивает строку до нужного вида учитывая спец символы, она не интересна в данном вопросе.

Вот эта функция создает поток и запускает распарсенную команду из полученной строки:

```
void    execute(t_main *main)
{
    char    *file_path;
    char    **command;
    pid_t   pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
        *(main->pid) = pid;
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        command = parse_command(main->gap->arg, main->gap->comm);//подготовка к 
        file_path = parse_filename(main->gap->comm, main->envp);//передаче в execve()
        main -> exit_status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
        execve(file_path, command, main->envp);
        perror(main->gap->comm);
        main -> exit_status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Что-то в коде может показаться лишним действием, но я удалил много функционала для сужения круга потенциальных ошибок.
В итоге вот что происходит по нажатию ctr-c:

```
admin@Daniils-MacBook-Pro minishell % ./minishell
minishell -> ^C
minishell -> ^C
minishell -> ^C
minishell -> ^C
minishell ->
```

Но запустив команду cat и нажав ctr-c моя программа 2 раза печатает "Minishell -> ":

```
minishell -> ^C
minishell -> ^C
minishell -> ^C
minishell -> ^C
minishell -> cat
ekrmflker^C
minishell -> minishell ->
```

Я предполагаю, что это из-за использования процессов вместе с перехватом сигнала. У меня не получается это исправить, любая информация будет полезна. Спасибо!

Comment: думаю, что Ваш signal_handler делает слишком много. Он должен выставлять булевый флажок и все. А главный цикл приложение - проверять этот флажок в ключевых местах.

Comment: Может быть и так, но ошибка все равно осталась.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Сходу не вижу, почему такой вывод (не  ясно, что именно происходит в обработчике сигнала). Ну, в любом случае, перед fork() я бы сделал `fflush(NULL)` для выталкивания всех буферов, а также проверял код возврата и errno после waitpid

Comment: @avp , fflush установил. После waitpid errno = 4, perror: Interrupted system call. Вроде бы ничего критичного, системный вызов прерван... В обработчике сигнала просто очищается буфер, который, возможно, был записан(minishell -> buffer). Строка "minishell -> " к этому не относится и в моем коде не изменяется, как я понял. Ошибка все равно осталась((

Comment: у вас при старте программы переменная указатель `main->pid` имеет неопределённый указатель куда-то. Всё ведет к неопределённому поведению. Может быть вы её ещё где-то инициализируете. Ничего не видно. Мало информации. Покажите саму структуру `t_main`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, в parser() инициализируются массив pid_t *pid. Это связанно с тем, что при наличии пайпов мне нужно несколько дочерних процессов. В коде выше я упростил до одного pid и одного дочернего процесса. Но все же в коде выше массив pid.ов проинициализируется двумя элементами равными -1, далее в execute() первый элемент массива в родительском процессе приравняется к pid.у дочернего и выйдя из execute будет ожидать завершения. Я мог бы дать ссылку с проектом на GitHub, если вы на него посмотрите. Здесь выкладывать весь проект не хотелось бы, займет много места.

Comment: @Cleonia, *`"После waitpid errno = 4, perror: Interrupted system call."`* -- значит надо повторять waitpid, пока не прочтете завершение процесса (или errno, что такого pid больше нет)

Comment: @avp Я попробовал, на первом проходе errno = 4 или 0, на втором 10(пид зомби вроде). Ничего не изменилось. Я думаю дело в readline, нужен человек хорошо понимающий механизм его работы, там же тоже свой обработчик сигналов. И кстати, это учебное задание, мне доступны только 3 функции управления readline:
rl_on_new_line(); rl_replace_line(); rl_redisplay();

Comment: @Cleonia, *`"дело в readline, ..., там же тоже свой обработчик сигналов"`* -- тогда вам надо разобраться, что именно он делает. Вообще, вызывается ли ваш `signal_handler()`? И напишите тут, что конкретно делают фнукции, вызываемые из signal_handler (я, например, решительно не помню). Кстати, последуйте совету, который вам тут давали, вытащите их вызов из обработчика. Вряд ли внутри они содержат только [signal-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) (либо в доке на readline явно разрешают их вызывать из обработчиков)

Comment: Кстати, errno надо анализировать **только если вызов вернул ошибку** (т.е. **-1**) В противном случае там может быть код, совершенно не относящийся  *к вашему* вызову функции

Comment: @avp, 1) "Вообще, вызывается ли ваш signal_handler()?", да, меняю его - меняется и работа кода. 2) "И напишите тут, что конкретно делают фнукции" rl_on_new_line() - просто нужна, сообщает readline.у, что сделан '\n' без ее участия, rl_replace_line() - заменяет буфер readline, написанный после приглашения(то что в фигурных скобках): "minishell -> {Hello World}" на то что в аргументе, rl_redisplay() выводит приглашение и буфер, на экран по запросу. "вытащите их вызов из обработчика": да, это нужно сделать, но выполнение необходимо ежесекундно, а просто подняв флаг я получу результат не сразу.

Comment: @Cleonia, какой вы получаете вывод, если не вызываете эти функции в обработчике? И какой у вас вывод при нормальном завершении команды в `execute()`? Примеры лучше приведите в тексте вопроса (добавьте в конец)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я сам нашел решение, вот так я изменил некоторые строки в execute():

```
pid = fork();
if (pid != 0)
    signal(SIGINT, empty_signal_handler); //пустая функция
```

Не до конца понимаю почему это работает, но видимо при получении сигнала ctr-C родительский процесс выполнял обработчик и снова ждал завершение дочернего процесса. Соответственно в том случае если
дочерний процесс это копия "minishell"(minishell -> ./minishell), то оба процесса выполняли обработчик и печатали "minishell -> ". Если дочерним процессом был, к примеру, "cat", то по ctr-C он завершался, а родитель выполнял и обработчик, и заходил на следующий виток цикла (while в main()), соответственно так же "minishell -> " печатался 2 раза.
Еще раз оговорюсь, что я протестировал код множественными кейсами и он делает то что мне нужно, но не до конца понимаю почему это работает. **Если вы зашли на эту страницу и знаете больше чем я, пожалуйста, напишите ответ**. Описание функций из обработчика сигналов оставлю в комментариях.

Comment: Поздновато увидел (уже задал вопрос в комментарии). На самом деле вы так отменяете предыдущий обработчик в основном процессе. Теперь он всегда будет крутиться с ним. Т.е. вместо заказа нового обработчика можно просто выбросить все вызовы функций readline из старого. Мне кажется, что это должно работать

Comment: @avp, не совсем, вот еще добавил кое что в main(), после while(1) переопределяю обработчик обратно на основной.
То есть я переопределяю потом обратно, как только родительский процесс продолжит работу. А если все выкинуть из основного обработчика, то получится вот так: "readline -> cat" ctr-C "readline -> catreadline -> cat", и так дальше, в одну строку, не удаляя лишний буфер после "приглашения" и не делая перенос строки.